# How to cast layout manager to GridLayoutManager using recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, androidx

How can I do the following piece of code without the use of androidx and just using normal RecyclerView?
Note: Im using kotlin

```
layoutManager is androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
```

Answer (score 0):

To cast something in Kotlin, you have to use `as` keyword.

```
val a = layoutManager as GridLayoutManager
```